# How to call localhost Handler efficiently with Go Gin? And how to get the running url?

Tags: go, go-gin

I reach a situation that inside a Go Gin Handler, I need to call another handler.

I figured that composing a new gin.Context object is hard, so it maybe easier just make a request to localhost, which going through the router although it is not necessary.

So is there a more efficient method that I can call directly another handler?

However it comes to that how to get the running URL ? Of course it can be hard coded since it is known, but is there a function like below?

```
ts := httptest.NewServer(GetMainEngine())
defer ts.Close()

log.Println(GetJWTMiddleware())
// here ts.URL is the running url in test
req, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", ts.URL + "/u/login", bytes.NewBuffer(loginPostString))
```

How to get the `ts.URL` with just gin?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to call another handler is not to.  Instead, abstract the common logic to a new function, and call that.  Example:

```
func handler1(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    path := r.URL.Path()
    row := r.URL.Query().Get("rowid")
    /* ... do something here with path and row ... */
    w.Write(someResponse)
}

func handler2(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    path := "/some/hard-coded/default"
    /* ... call handler1 ... */
}
```

Change this to:

```
func handler1(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    path := r.URL.Path()
    row := r.URL.Query().Get("rowid")
    someResponse, err := common(path, row)
    w.Write(someResponse)
}

func handler2(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    path := "/some/hard-coded/default"
    row := r.URL.Query().Get("someRowID")
    result, err := common(path, row)
    w.Write(result)
}

func common(path, row string) (interface{}, error) {
    /* ... do something here with path and row ... */
}
```

As a general rule, the only thing calling your handler functions should be your mux/router, and your unit tests.